# I am trying to read information from a .csv and put it into an array in C#. Can anyone tell me why the code doesn't work?

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, split

EDIT: Solved through comments

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Details.csv");
```

in the file there is

[5 usernames and 5 passwords, they should be split with a comma because they were in separate cells in excel but they've both been put in one cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTXhg.png)

```
//reading in details
            string[ , ] data = new string[hML, 3];
            string[] tempArr = new string[3];
            string lineIn = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < hML; i++)
            {
                lineIn = sr.ReadLine();
                tempArr = lineIn.Split(Convert.ToChar(","));
                data[i, 0] = tempArr[0];
                data[i, 1] = tempArr[1];
                data[i, 2] = tempArr[2];
            }
```

when it trys to split at the comma I get a "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" error and i have no idea what it means

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214331/discussion-on-question-by-youngcompscientist-i-am-trying-to-read-information-fro).

Answer (score 0):

It means that you're trying to access object before initialization if I were to hazard a guess I'd say it's sr variable, aa there is no declaration of it in the code you posted.

Comment: it is declared 20 lines before this section, I didn't think it was necessary to show all of the code.

Comment: Yes and no... in this case we have to guess what type sr represents

Comment: @StewartRitchie sr is the name for my streamReader